# Fix headphones ear pads

Tags: repair

I have a nice pair of over-ear headphones but the ear pads *cracked apart*. Any idea on how to fix this is very welcome.
Photos:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, "small appliance repair" is off-topic here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a small gadget repair question...

Answer (score 1):

Clean both surfaces and use either Superglue or a glue gun to stick those two surfaces together.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a replacement set of pads, remove the damaged pads, clean the surface, apply the new pads (typically an adhesive mounting.)